# Need a unique List of JPA entites

Tags: list, unique, openjpa

I am attempting to get a unique List of JPA entities... I can't do it by adding a Distinct clause in the named query because I will be adding these entities to a list from multiple entities.  So I decided to do the uniqueness inside the code...
Using eclipse and some OpenJPA tools I have added a default hashCode and an Equlas Method to the Entity Bean...

After doing that I created an ArrayList, And added all entity objects to it I do the following...

```
return new ArrayList(new HashSet(personListRetVal));
```

I think that should return a unique list...  Any advice?  How can I return an ordered unique List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)?